# JQuery UI API changed for grabbing data on draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I used to be able to grab a draggable data and assign it to another.  However it looks like the newest JQuery UI has changed and this currently doesnt work.  I am using JQuery UI 1.12.1.  What is the new way to do this?

```
 var draggableData = $(draggle).data('draggable');

  $(draggle).data('draggable', draggableData);
```

Comment: Review Instance and Widget: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/ I am pretty sure you're looking for Instance.

Comment: I agree, but how do I assign the data back...

Comment: This: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/widget-method-invocation/ should help clarify that. If that does not help, then provide a jsFiddle and can work on it.

Comment: It might just be as simple as using `ui-draggable` instead for your Data reference.

Comment: I think you maybe right, but assigning the data to another draggable. I see you can do one option. `$(draggle).data(draggableData)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
var draggableData = $(dragA).data('ui-draggable');

$(dragB).data('ui-draggable', draggableData);
```

> To retrieve the instance object, call `jQuery.data()` using the widget's full name as the key.

This should work for you.